# CakePHP newbie question: How to add non-database attribute to model?

Tags: cakephp

I want to create a model that has SOME attributes that are not stored in a database. For example, I want to maintain an "age" field in the model, but I only store birthday information in the database (I can calculate "age" once the DOB info has been loaded). I tried adding a simple attribute to a model extension, but as far as I can tell, it's ignored by CakePHP. What's the proper way to go about accomplishing this?

I'm a CakePHP novice, so forgive me if I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd do it using the [afterFind](http://book.cakephp.org/view/681/afterFind) callback method in the model.

Comment: +1 That sounds promising.  Just calculate age and stick it in some property.

Answer (score 3):

It's been a while since I dealt with Cake, but why not just implement a getAge() method?

Comment: I prefer this solution. It's explicit and documented in a logical location. `afterFind()` would work, of course, but it hides the logic more than I'd like. The availability of an `age` property would look like magic to new developers.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using CakePHP 1.3, you could use the 'virtual field':
http://book.cakephp.org/view/1608/Virtual-fields
[Cookbook 3.7.10]

[edit] It also works in CakePHP 2.x:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html

The main advantage of this approach is that the virtual field is added in the model. That way, the MVC principles are respected.

example (MySQL):

```
var $virtualFields = array(
    'age' => "YEAR(NOW()) - YourModelHere.dob"
);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of doing it with cake.

1. Use virtual fields http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html
2. Use call back function afterFind() http://changelog.in/2012/07/alternative-to-cakephps-virtual-fields-which-is-far-less-restrictive/

Answer (score -1):

Use the class `Cache`:

```
$parametrs = array('age'=>21, 'name'=>'aziz');
Cache::write('myOptions', $parameters);

Cache::read('myOptions');
```